# VSIX Color Editor tool

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Does somebody know where I can find the "VSIX Color Editor" tool that is described on the following MSDN page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/extensibility/internals/vsix-color-editor?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN

There is no download link, and I think it's also not included with the SDK itself.

Comment: It was for me (2015), its located @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Tools\Bin\

Comment: agree with Eli Dagan, Do you resolve the issue? if the issue still exists, please feel free let me know, if the answer is helpful, please mark it answer, it will be beneficial for other communities.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the link at the [following](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2015ColorThemeEditor)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the Visual Studio SDK installed as well as base Visual Studio. For Visual Studio 2017, it can be found in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017[SKU]\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Tools\Bin